# Patching Items Doesn't Update Validity in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms

I've a problem because after i submit the form, even though there's a value, the "field is required" doesn't disappear. It supposed to disappear. Is there something wrong with my validity? Please see this link [See this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/patch-info-using-id-and-index-vfryh6?file=app/app.component.ts)

> TS

```
patchValues(id, i) {
let x = (<FormArray>this.addForm.controls['rows']).at(i);

const selectedIngredient = this.ingredients.find(y => y.id == id);

x.patchValue({
  unit_price: selectedIngredient.price
});
```

}

Comment: Try using `x.updateValueAndValidity()` after patching the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these cases, you have to trigger a validity check with (for example) :

```
x.patchValue({
  unit_price: selectedIngredient.price
});
x.get('unit_price').markAsTouched();
```

When patching a value, validators aren't executed.

Working [fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/patch-info-using-id-and-index-g21stl?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

After patching values in  form you should mark it **touched** to display errors

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/patch-info-using-id-and-index-dvnngq)

```
patchValues(id, i) {
   let x = (<FormArray>this.addForm.controls['rows']).at(i);

   const selectedIngredient = this.ingredients.find(y => y.id == id);

   x.patchValue({
     unit_price: selectedIngredient.price
   });
  this.markFormGroupTouched(this.addForm)
}
```

To mark complete form as touched:

```
    /**
     * Marks all controls in a form group as touched
     * @param formGroup - The group to caress
    */
    markFormGroupTouched(formGroup: FormGroup) {
        if (Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(formGroup, 'controls')) {
            (<any>Object).values(formGroup.controls).forEach(control => {
                if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
                    // FormGroup
                    this.markFormGroupTouched(control);
                } else if (control instanceof FormArray) {
                    control.controls.forEach(c => {
                        if (c instanceof FormGroup)
                            this.markFormGroupTouched(c);
                    });
                }
                // FormControl
                control.markAsTouched();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have given demo check it

Comment: Haha again you answered later than Cetia. Anyway i upvoted you

Comment: Hey can i ask for help. I added quantity in my code. How come it isnt valid when i set it to [0, Validators.required]?

Comment: Hello did younget it?

Comment: Yes I will give u answer wait .

Comment: can you share updated code. I am not getting problem properly.

Comment: can you share updated code. I am not getting problem properly.

Comment: Please check the same stackblitz link above

Comment: Check whether it works fine i updated it. ping me back ----> https://stackblitz.com/edit/patch-info-using-id-and-index-ohezyl

Comment: Thanks. It works but can you shorten it? Just use Cetia solution above. And add some function to update validity for quantity only

Comment: I have used my  solution not  Cetia's just add my function.

Comment: No change just added one function check edit in stackblitz.com/edit/patch-info-using-id-and-index-ohezyl